# How to fix Rails 5.2 application bundler issue for AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to deploy Rails 5.2 application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I am getting this error.

`Creating application version archive "app-c6b5-190405_225348".
Uploading example-rails52/app-c6b5-190405_225348.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: example-eb-rails52-env
  Application name: example-rails52
  Region: us-east-2
  Deployed Version: app-c6b5-190405_225348
  Environment ID: e-ehbkcfzrrt
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2::platform/Puma with Ruby 2.5 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.2
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: UNKNOWN
  Updated: 2019-04-05 16:53:59.311000+00:00
Printing Status:
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-525254074082 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
INFO: Created security group named: sg-073de6677d8e02d77
INFO: Created load balancer named: awseb-e-e-AWSEBLoa-985TNPDWPYRI
INFO: Created security group named: awseb-e-ehbkcfzrrt-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1XWZBQC4TD76I
INFO: Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-ehbkcfzrrt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-SAZWMJ3L0UV7
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-ehbkcfzrrt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1E8GGM4K5S26
INFO: Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-2:525254074082:scalingPolicy:bb866da3-dac2-47f0-81a2-ebc1c582d68a:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-ehbkcfzrrt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1E8GGM4K5S26:policyName/awseb-e-ehbkcfzrrt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-ON6YTENHUIOE
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-2:525254074082:scalingPolicy:f13cedac-d71f-4b89-a0fd-dd2db97bb43a:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-ehbkcfzrrt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1E8GGM4K5S26:policyName/awseb-e-ehbkcfzrrt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-3MK7B2H0O52F
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-ehbkcfzrrt-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-1R89A12TU33EK
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-ehbkcfzrrt-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-1KHMKXF2A73T1
ERROR: [Instance: i-050185633c1ecb322] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...:in`find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/bundle:23:in`'. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].`

Can some one give me solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 5.2 you have to install bundler 2.0.1 version. To fix this issue you can follow below steps -

Step #1. You have add eb extensions for installing bundler 2.0.1 version to AWS Elastic beanstalk -

```
# Go to your project root directory
$ mkdir .ebextensions
$ vim .ebextensions/bundler_install.config 

  files:
    # Runs before `./10_bundle_install.sh`:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/09_gem_install_bundler.sh" :
      mode: "000775"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
        #! /bin/bash

        EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir)
        EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
        # Source the application's ruby, i.e. 2.6. Otherwise it will be 2.3, which will give this error: `bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0`
        . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

        cd $EB_APP_STAGING_DIR
        echo "Installing compatible bundler"
        gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
```

Step #2. Go to AWS Elastic beanstalk All applications ->  example-rails52 -> example-eb-rails52-env then click Configuration -> Software -> Modify and then added this env variable

```
 BUNDLER_VERSION=2.0.1
```

and click save

Step #3. Deploy the app again

```
$ eb deploy
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: Horrendous. No chance am I putting that into a hook. There has to be a better solution? Containers, I suppose.

Comment: @DamienRoche I updated the answer. Please check it again. I hope it will work.